# Find first bit set and unset it atomically

Tags: optimization, locking, bit-manipulation, atomic

I'm looking for instructions (x86 machine) or optimization for the following line of code:

```
lock()
int x = ffs(words); // find first bit that set
long words = unset(x, words); // unset the bit "x" in "words"
unlock()
```

I don't know how to do this without locking.

Comment: I doubt you can, unless there is a machine instruction allowing this type of operation.

Comment: I fear you'll need to settle for a compare-and-exchange spin-loop for this. How wide is the bitfield?

Comment: A binary search would at least make such a loop O(log). Though you'd probably spend more time on decisions than you theoretically save, especially when you consider that it wouldn't be practical to unroll.

Comment: is "first" most significant or least?

Comment: it's the least, according to the `ffs()` function. I will just need 64-bit or 128-bit for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

If `words` is an unsigned type, then the non-atomic computation can be done as follows:

```
words &= ~-words;
```

Or, equivalently

```
words &= words - 1;
```

That works because in `-words` (assuming 2's-complement, which unsigned types must use), the least-significant 1 and all the 0s to the right of it are unchanged, while all the bits to the left of the least significant 1 are inverted. So `words & ~-words` will be identical to `words` except for the least significant 1.

However, in order to do that atomically, you'll either need to use a lock as indicated in the question, or you'll need to do a spin-loop around an atomic compare-and-exchange.

Comment: I actually need the bit as well, not just simply unset it. How do I know which bit is set ? And moreover this also requires lock.

Comment: @w00d: Do you mean that you need the bit, or you need the index of the bit? The bit is `words & -words`, but to get the index of the bit you need to use something like `ffs`. I know that it requires a lock: I said so in the last paragraph. There is no way to do this without some kind of external synchronization, either a lock or a compare-and-swap or equivalent.

Comment: it's the index of the bit.